# Can't figure out what's wrong in my code

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-dump

I have a dump file which I managed to create, from my DLL which is created for any unhandled exception.

When I did something like `int* tt = new int[4]; return int[n];` with n = 4, I would get the dump file, and could open it, and see at what line the error is caused. This was possible for both directly from a release exe, and a release DLL.

Now this was an easy error, and I only entered it to test my memory dump creation.

I now have a 900kb dump file, and the event log says the error comes from my .DLL, yet if I open the file, it does not display any source code.

The call stack is

> KERNELBASE.dll!RaiseException()  + 0x3d bytes
>       clr.dll!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly()  + 0x18f bytes
>       clr.dll!IL_Throw()  + 0xe2 bytes
>       000007fe81f65fd7()
>       00000000034d1610()
>       000000002d06ecb8()
>       436f93ce00050011()
>       436f93cf00110012()
>       000000002d06ec50()
>       00006d930c4f7680()
>       clr.dll!InlinedCallFrame::`vftable'()
>       000000002d06f3d8()

which does not help me at all to figure out where in the DLL my error is coming from.
Another issue with debugging this is, it only happens on a live-PC, but never on my debugging system. Can anyone help me finding a way how to debug this? It seems to happen on the calling of the DLL, but: not every time, only like every 2nd time (sometimes on 1st try, sometimes on 5th). I am completely lost on what is happening here.

Edit:
Updated the call stack with the Microsoft symbols loaded, but I still do not know where this may be coming from.

Comment: This was just a way to prove that my memory dump function was working. If I call it with return int[4]; I would get an access error, which is the same as I am getting now, but I am not aware of where the access error may happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the symbols for kernelbase.dll.  And possibly clr.dll.

Presumably you are using visual studio? 
Set it up to access symbols from the microsoft symbol server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.80).aspx

You may need to right click on items in the callstack and tell it to load symbols.

Additionally be sure to keep a copy of the pdb file for any releases of software you make.

Comment: Okay, done, but it still is purely in the Microsoft DLLs, so I don't know why the exception is raised. It's a memory access apparently, but no idea why.

Comment: So whats next that is unknown on the callstack?
Load symbols for that.
If it is your executable, then add a symbol path to a folder containing that version of the executable and the pdb file for that version.  Then get it to load symbols for that line on the callstack.

Comment: Thats the point, there is nothing of my application on the callstack. // okay, turns out the camera's API was causing the error. Thanks for the hint with the Microsoft Symbol base! Confusing though that it says my DLL is the cause, but the DLL is not using the Camera API at all...